# Is this a ruby's bug in class Matrix?

Tags: ruby, matrix, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I use Matrix class in ruby to caculate eigenvalues and eigenvectors. With this code:

```
m = Matrix[[0.6868,0.6067],[0.6067,0.5978]]
v, d, v_inv = m.eigensystem
```

the correct result should be:

```
[ 1.25057433  0.03398123]
[[ 0.73251454 -0.68075138]
 [ 0.68075138  0.73251454]]
```

which I confirmed with `numpy` using Python.

However, I got the result below:

```
d=[[0.033970204576497576,   0],
 [0,    1.2506297954235022]]

v=[[0.6807528514962294, 0.7325131774785713],
 [-0.7325131774785713,  0.6807528514962294]]
```

Is this a ruby's bug? My ruby's version below:

```
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-linux]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be by no mean an answer, but I’ll put it here for the sake of formatting:

When it comes to math, I would use [r](/questions/tagged/r) to check the *correctness* of the result:

```
> entries <- c(0.6868, 0.6067, 0.6067, 0.5978)
> input <- matrix(entries, nrow=2, byrow=TRUE)
> input

#        [,1]   [,2]
# [1,] 0.6868 0.6067
# [2,] 0.6067 0.5978

> input_eigen <- eigen(input)
> input_eigen 

$values
# [1] 1.2506298 0.0339702

$vectors
#            [,1]       [,2]
# [1,] -0.7325132  0.6807529
# [2,] -0.6807529 -0.7325132
```

I trust the result above, which means ruby is probably doing better, than python/numpy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
And could you tell me that why is ruby better than python/numpy on this question in your opinion?

Comment: As I wrote in the summary, I trust [tag:r] more than both [tag:ruby] and [tag:python] when it comes to math. And ruby result is the same as the one yielded with R, while python’s one is not.

Comment: OK, I got it.
Thanks ^^

Comment: @Ireul, you marked this as the correct answer. Does that mean that you checked it from another source (wolfram/by hand) and found that numpy was indeed wrong? If it is, isn't it even more interesting than your original question? Did you ask a follow up question somewhere or contact the package maintainers or something?